# Xcode6.1 testObject.saveinbackgroud( )

Tags: swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

I am trying to use Parse but I can't add an `testObject.saveinbackgroud()` 
When I try I getting an error.
I tried to find an answer on the web but didnt got any result. I believe a lot of people are having the same issue.

```
    var testObject: PFObject(className:"TestObject")
    testObject["foo"] = "bar"
    testObject.setObject("user1", forKey: "user")

    testObject.saveinbackgroud()
```

Comment: You've misspelt `saveInBackground()`. It works perfectly with Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found that **xcode6.1** will use the `.save()` and not `.saveInBackground`.

```
var testObject: PFObject(className:"TestObject")
testObject["foo"] = "bar"
testObject.setObject("user1", forKey: "user")

testObject.save()
```